# Can't get to understand word counting in C

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, state, getchar

[SOLVED]
I recently asked a question about some code which I thought I really understood well.

But after a few days when I looked back for revision, new question arose from the same piece of code (adopted from THE C PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE Second Edition by Brian. W. Kernighnan (ISBN-13: 978-8131704943)).

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN  1
#define OUT 0

main()
{
    int nw, c, state;
    state = OUT;
    nw = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if (state == OUT)
        {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", nw);
}
```

So I did some random test and found thing I couldn't explain or understand:

1. Why does the code not work when I have

   `state = OUT` after `nw = 0`

When I normally ran this code it gave me correct no. of words but however when I interchange the order of the `state = OUT and nw = 0` it always returned answer equal to 0 why is that so??
I know order is important in C, but why this specific order only??

2.What is the meaning of if-else stament in brief??

3.Acc. to the book the state var. was define as to define whether getchar was inside a word or not but I don't get it how exactly does the state var. do so ??

4.<strike>Also what is with the author use of equivalence and equality ??
I noticed when he is making a condition/s he uses equivalence, else uses equality, am I right??</strike>

Thank You...

Comment: I think you copied the code here incorrectly.  The `state == OUT;` line after the `if (c == ...` should use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because correcting a typo solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry a typo,(corrected script) but I did really like to know about the script, Please don't mark it off-topic.........

Comment: Not an answer, but calling a C source file a script is quite confusing...  Also, are you sure part 1 of your question is still valid after the edit?

Comment: Please don't bash OP for his language problems. Not everybody speaks perfect English.

Comment: oh thannks @Chris I  really misunderstood the author

Comment: @fvu yes the question 1 is still valid  I did correct the typo and still gave me word count as zero...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you posted with some comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN  1 // in the code below, whenever you see IN, it's replaced by 1
#define OUT 0 // same as IN, but for 0

int main(void) {
  int nw, c, state; // nw is the number of the words
  // c stands for the character we get from input and state is the state that are
  // currently.

  // init state as OUT
  state = OUT;
  // init counter to 0
  nw = 0;

  // while user doesn't give EOF
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

    // we found whitespace, newline or tab
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
      state = OUT;                            // put state as OUT,
    // so that we do not count them as words
    else if (state == OUT) {                  // enter here only if state is OUT
      // Now, we see that we found a letter/number, which means that a word
      // was typed by the user.

      // set state as IN, so that we remember that we are eating the characters of
      // the word given (in the next loops)
      state = IN;

      // increase the counter of the words
      ++nw;
    }
  }

  // print the number of words received by the user
  printf("%d", nw);
  return 0;
}
```

Now, let's take a look at a sample input:

```
sam
dad
```

and of course the output (as you should guess from the comments above) is:

`2`

Let's run the (interesting) code step by step for input `sam`:

```
// input: "sam" (without the quotes)

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { // eat first character, i.e. 's'

  /****** 1st execution of the loop ********************/

  // 's' is not going into this if
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
    state = OUT;
  // first time we execute the loop so state is OUT,
  // thus we enter the loop
  else if (state == OUT) {

    // set state as IN
    state = IN;

    // increase the counter of the words
    ++nw;
  }

  /****************************************************/

  /****** 2nd execution of the loop ********************/
  // while loop's getchar() gives as 'a'

  // 'a' is not going into this if
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
    state = OUT;
  // state is IN, so we don't go into this loop
  else if (state == OUT) {
    state = IN;
    ++nw;
  }

  /****************************************************/


  /****** 3rd execution of the loop ********************/
  // same as 2nd, but for 'm'

  /****************************************************/


  /****** 4rth execution of the loop ********************/
  // while loop's getchar() gives as '\n'

  // '\n' is going into this if (the c == '\n' is true
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
    state = OUT;                // state sets to OUT

  // we are not going into this if else, since we already entered the above if!
  else if (state == OUT) {
    state = IN;
    ++nw;
  }

  /****************************************************/


  /****** 5th execution of the loop ********************/
  // while loop's getchar() gives as 'd' (first letter of dad)

  // 'd' is not going into this if
  if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
    state = OUT;
  // state is OUT, so we go into this loop
  else if (state == OUT) {
    // set state as IN
    state = IN;

    // increase counter
    ++nw;
  }

  /****************************************************/

  // and so on :)
}
```

First make sure you understand this and then answer your own questions you did. :)

Also, we call this code, not script. Don't be in a hurry for getting into scripts.

Comment: Thank You, but could you tell me how state = in eats out the characters?? And I'm sorry for causing the confusion too......

Comment: @ArchKudo you are welcome. For me, there is no problem caused. :) `getchar()` is the one that eats the characters. When `state` is `IN`, the `else if` part will not be executed (since it's condition it's going to be false). Moreover, assuming that we are reading a letter at that time, `state` equal to `IN` will make as not entering either the `if` or the `else if`, thus skipping that letter. Hope that helps and the answer is good enough for you to accept it.

Comment: Oo finally understood it, so it's more like it enters state = IN when a letter is typed so it stops counting letters and again starts counting when a whitespace or new line is met.....Thank you so much......

Comment: Exactly @ArchKudo, but change 'counting letters' to 'counting words', because the code is intended to count how many words the user typed. But I guess you just made a typo. :) Since it's your relative new, but did good in reading all my answer and comments and finally understood, I am going to upvote your questin for balancing the -1. :)